# Mail 7.3 with iMac running 10.9

Tags: mail.app, email, imac, printing

I just upgraded from an iMac with 10.6 to a newer iMac with 10.9. When I use the Mail 7.3 program and go to print and email, it prints all previous emails from the same sender as well. I don't want all the other emails printed, just the current one. Is there a way to disable the other emails from printing, or to disable the grouping of emails?  Thank you...

Comment: Are all emails a part of same email?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about same email with multiple messages (emails) in it.

In order to print specific email embedded in that email chain:

Select the single message window: It will have a highlighted border.

The other emails will be separated with page separator.

It looks like this (sorry I had to black out my personal info), but you can see 3 emails in this chain and only the top one is selected for printing.

[image: multiple emails]

In top Right (circled) of that window you will find the Print Icon, that will print the selected message only.